# QUnit testing a function which leans on document properties

Tags: unit-testing, google-apps-script, qunit

I'm trying to write some unit tests for an Apps Script add-on designed for Google Docs. A few of the functions I'd like to have unit tests for call `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()`. A simple example function in my add-on:

```
function baseFontSize() {
  var baseFontSize = JSON.parse(
      PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('baseFontSize'));
  if (baseFontSize === null) {
    baseFontSize = JSON.parse(
        PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('baseFontSize'));
    if (baseFontSize === null) {
      PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('baseFontSize', '11');
      baseFontSize = 11;
    }
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
        .setProperty('baseFontSize', JSON.stringify(baseFontSize));
  }
  return baseFontSize;
}
```

I'm writing my tests with the QUnit for Google Apps Script library:

```
function doGet(e) {
  QUnit.urlParams(e.parameter);
  QUnit.config({title: 'My test suite'});
  QUnit.load(testSuite);
  return QUnit.getHtml();
}

QUnit.helpers(this);

function testSuite() {
  // some module() and test() calls deleted for brevity...

  test('baseFontSize', function() {
    // PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties() === null
    // how to test baseFontSize()?
  });

  // more module() and test() calls...
}
```

Since the test suite is not running within a document, there are no document properties. It seems that the only way to test my function would be to mock the `getDocumentProperties` function. Of course, the only Apps Script mock/stub libraries I can find are either meant to test within a Node.js environment, or are not sufficiently complete for my needs, which means I would have to roll my own.

Comment: I think it does still have an HTML document... maybe just not the one you expect

Comment: @jakerella, `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties` returns the `Properties` class instance associated with the currently-active Document, Sheet, or Form. Not HtmlOutput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still hope to find a more elegant solution, until that occurs I have thrown together a simple stub framework based on the SinonJS API, and I'm injecting the stub into my function to be tested (since I can't actually stub `PropertiesService`, as it's frozen).

Roughly, my solution (my project already includes Underscore, so I take advantage of it where I can):

```js
function stub(object, property, impl) {
  const original = object[property];
  if (_.isFunction(impl)) object[property] = wrapFunction(impl);
  else object[property] = wrapFunction(function() { return impl; });
  object[property].restore = function() {
    if (!_.isUndefined(original)) object[property] = original;
    else delete object[property];
  };
  return object[property];
}

function wrapFunction(fn) {
  const properties = _.mapObject({
    get callCount() { return calls.length; },
    get called() { return calls.length > 0; },
    get notCalled() { return calls.length === 0; },
    // etc...
  }, function(v, k, o) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, k); });
  const calls = [];
  const wrappedFn = function() {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var error;
    var returnVal;
    try { returnVal = fn.apply(this, args); }
    catch (e) { error = e; }
    calls.push({
      thisObj: this,
      params: args,
      error: error,
      returnVal: returnVal,
    });
    return returnVal;
  };
  Object.defineProperties(wrappedFn, properties);
  return wrappedFn;
}
```

Then, my test:

```js
test('baseFontSize', function() {
  const propService = {};
  stub(propService, 'getDocumentProperties', fakeGetProperties());
  stub(propService, 'getUserProperties', fakeGetProperties());
  equal(baseFontSize(propService), 11);
});

//...

function fakeGetProperties() {
  const map = {};
  const container = {
    deleteAllProperties: function() {_.each(map, function(v, k){depete map[k];});},
    deleteProperty: function(k) { delete map[k]; },
    getKeys: function() { return Object.keys(map); },
    getProperties: function() { return _.clone(map); },
    getProperty: function(key) { return map[key] || null; },
    setProperties: function(obj, deleteOthers) {
      if (deleteOthers) container.deleteAllProerties();
      _.each(obj, function(v, k) { map[k] = v; });
    },
    setProperty: function(key, value) { map[key] = value; },
  };
  return function() { return container; };
}
```

And the edited version of my function to test, with DI for PropertiesService:

```js
function baseFontSize(propService) {
  if (_.isUndefined(propService)) {
    propService = PropertiesService;
  }

  var baseFontSize = JSON.parse(
      propService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('baseFontSize'));
  if (baseFontSize === null) {
    baseFontSize = JSON.parse(
        propService.getUserProperties().getProperty('baseFontSize'));
    if (baseFontSize === null) {
      propService.getUserProperties().setProperty('baseFontSize', '11');
      baseFontSize = 11;
    }
    propService.getDocumentProperties()
        .setProperty('baseFontSize', JSON.stringify(baseFontSize));
  }
  return baseFontSize;
}
```